# How to parse and retrieve the values in dynamic text panel

Tags: handlebars.js, grafana

I am trying to get in my dynamic text panel (grafana) value of a math expression query that I can see it exists, see source panel data:

```
{
  "state": "Done",
  "series": [
    {
      "refId": "press0",
      "meta": {
        "type": "numeric-multi",
        "typeVersion": [
          0,
          1
        ]
      },
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "_value",
          "type": "number",
          "typeInfo": {
            "frame": "float64",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "config": {},
          "values": [
            1010.1793156417567
          ],
      "entities": {},
      "state": {
        "calcs": {
          "sum": 1010.1793156417567,
          "max": 1010.1793156417567,
          "min": 1010.1793156417567,
          "logmin": 1010.1793156417567,
          "mean": 1010.1793156417567,
          "last": 1010.1793156417567,
          "first": 1010.1793156417567,
          "lastNotNull": 1010.1793156417567,
          "firstNotNull": 1010.1793156417567,
          "count": 1,
          "nonNullCount": 1,
          "allIsNull": false,
          "allIsZero": false,
          "range": 0,
          "diff": 0,
          "delta": 0,
          "step": null,
          "diffperc": 0,
          "previousDeltaUp": true
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "length": 1
},...
```

How can parse this source and get for `"refId": "press0"` the `"values": [1010.1793156417567]`?

I don't mind if I do this with the content language Handlebars or HTML or Markdown which I can select in the panel.

[image]

Comment: I'm not certain what you are asking for but maybe this code can get you started down the right path: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/5m1kayn4/